# Multiple value Checkbox jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to get the values of a checkbox and assign the values checked to all checkboxed with the same id on the page. However my attempt is not working, here is what I'm doing

```
       $('.add_button').click(function() {   //they click a div named added
        selected=$('#ssrBox').val();  //I get the id of the checkbox and the values however I only get one value.
        id=$(this).attr('id');  //I find the id of the div which is ssrBox
        $('#ssrBox').change(function() {  // I find the rest of the checkboxes with the same id and hopefully make them select the same value
        $('#ssrBox').add(selected); //have the value being checked for all
      });



   <div class="grs-multi-select-area" style="height:120px;width:150px;">
  <div class="grs-multi-select-box ">
   <input id="ssrBox" class="ssremployeeid" type="checkbox" name="ssremployeeid[]"
   value="1312">
       Amanda Becker
    </div>
     <div class="grs-multi-select-box "> // same as above I just collapsed it for viewing purposes
     <div class="grs-multi-select-box ">
     <div class="grs-multi-select-box ">
</div> //closes main div
```

I'm not getting the value for the checkbox and nothing is being checked. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: <<to all checkboxed with the same id on the page>> IDs must be unique on context page. For ugly coding use as selector: `$(':checkbox[id=ssrBox]')`

Comment: @roasted I want all the checkboxes to be the same value though? Im a little lost

Comment: An id should ALWAYS be unique. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite confused with what you are trying to execute.
You click a Div or a Checkbox?

The following might help -
Give a class to all the checkboxes.

Something like

```
$('#yourCheckboxID').click(function(){
    var checkboxValue = $(this).val();
    $('.yourCheckboxClass').attr('value',checkboxValue);
});
```

I can help more if you could create a small demo on jsfiddle.

Comment: so I have 3 divs that are acting like buttons. once I click add I want to get the values of all the checkbox values that were clicked and assign them to all the checkboxes.